# Does anyone know what the name of the music is in episode 6 of Parasyte -the maxim- from 7:19 to about 8:30?

Tags: music, parasyte

I can't seem to find it on the official soundtrack, maybe I'm being a dumbie but if anyone has the answer then fair shout!!

It plays as Shinichi is setting off

> to get revenge for his mum's death.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The song you are looking for is named **"Solitude"** by Ken Arai. It's part of the official soundtrack.

[Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8FqbTz9N5Do) a link to the song on YouTube.

Comment: Yep, I agree that that's the piece in question. +1.